# Apple IOS OTP autofill SMS api correct criteria

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, backend

I see the API documented for IOS 12 on how to retrieve a OTP from SMS for your app password field. But I can't seem to find documentation for the other side... sending the OTP to a user. What is the criteria of an OTP that can be detected by IOS for the user to autofill. For example is there a character limit or a certain pattern that must be followed.

I am referring to this iOS feature https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/04/safari-security-code-auto-fill/

Specifically what is the criteria of an OTP to be received by this api. If I sms a user “your one time passcode is: thebirdwenttothepark” would it be picked up? Obviously there is a specification that defines what an OTP is according to iOS.

Answer (score 3):

The message that is received should just contain "code" or "passcode" in it. You should check [this](https://medium.com/@shankarmadeshvaran/how-to-implement-automatic-otp-verification-in-ios-7813c6116a1d) medium article if you need more detail.

**EDIT**

- The code that is sent must be numbers only (integers) and must be minimum of 4 digits and the maximum of 9 digits.
- It *can* contain spaces but it's recommended that it doesn't since the digit recognition can get complicated, for example `235 876` is recognized as is ("235 876 *with spaces included*"), but `2354 2356` only recognizes "354 2356"

And the text field that you have in the app on device should have

```swift
  if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        self.textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    }
```

You can test your codes on device before you start implementing it on the backend by using iMessage, simply send an iMessage to the device that you are testing (that has the text field with `.oneTimeCode` enabled) and it will pick up the codes.

Also I would recommend reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=z0i801mg) Apple resource about domain-bound codes that are a more secure way of using OTP (it is only supported from iOS 14 and Big Sur)

Comment: Example 1
"Please enter your one time code: 123abc"
Example 2
"code:apple"
Example 3
"code:the bird went to the park"

What would the behavior be? Would it pick up only the word park or the entire phrase? Are OTP allowed to have spaces? Underscores?

Comment: @CodeCamper sorry I misunderstood the question at first, I have edited the answer for the real question and tested all your examples and explained how you can test any combination you want to try yourself before implementing it on the backend.